# What does the phrase "Oh, he died an energetic you need more TV!" mean in this Ape Escape 3 cutscene?

Tags: video-games, ape-escape

On 5:48 in the above cutscene of *Ape Escape 3*, a character says:

> Oh, he died an energetic you need more TV!

I don't understand. What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a clearer version [here](https://youtu.be/lLgw-TjfLHI?si=rksLyw_rnPPUM2Uv&t=281).

> "How dare you be wide-eyed and energetic?"
> "You need more TV!"

As per the plot summary for the game, the TV broadcasts are putting people in trances.

> Specter, the Pipo Monkeys' leader, finds a Monkey Helmet, and hires the human scientist Dr. Tomoki (Dr. トモウキ, Dokutā Tomōki) to aid him in his evil plans. They establish television stations protected by the Freaky Monkey Five where they plan to broadcast TV shows worldwide. The television shows that are broadcast on every television put every human except the twins Kei and Yumi (Satoru and Sayaka outside of North America), their aunt Aki, and Natalie (Natsumi outside of North America) into a mindless trance. When Natalie informs Kei and Yumi that Spike (Kakeru), Jimmy (Hikaru) and the Professor were all infected by the television show, Kei and Yumi go out to catch the monkeys and thwart Specter and Tomoki.

Comment: So, I can understand, although not like, the localizers changing Japanese names to English names in North America. But changing Japanese names to *other Japanese names*?

Comment: @Adamant: It is a bit odd, although sometimes I think it's writers wanting to make their mark, like how someone editing a typo on this site might also change a few other things to hit the character threshold and/or make it look less like hedge trimming. I've also occasionally seen cases where it's to avoid a local pun/term, or to make the name But Not Too Foreign.